# Declaring void pointers to push type handling downstream

Tags: c, pointers, void

Is it ever common to do something like the following:

```
void *x = (void *) "one";
void *y = (void *) 2;
void *z = (void *) NULL;
```

Instead of:

```
char * x = "one";
int y = 2;
```

My reason for asking this is the ability to call a function that can accept multiple types. For example, a concat of various elements like is available in javascript. It seems like in a way using `(void *)` is just a simple way to mean "any type".

Comment: No, it prevents type-checking and is best avoided and cannot be used to avoid application of the *Strict Aliasing Rule*. It is valid, just not smart.

Comment: Actually, it is creating pointer to memory cell 0x2, not to constant `2` in second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because you can't dereference a void pointer: you have to know what type is being stored, rendering the idea useless.

What you might be looking for is a [variant type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type).

```
enum type {
    CHAR, INT, DOUBLE, STR
};

typedef struct {
    union {
        char   c;
        int    i;
        double d;
        char   *str;
    };
    enum type t;
} variant;

void displayGenericObjec(variant v)
{
    switch (v.t) {
        case CHAR:
            putchar(v.c);
            break;
        case INT:
            printf("%d", v.i);
            break;
        case DOUBLE:
            printf("%f", v.d);
            break;
        case STR:
            printf("%s", v.str);
            break;
    }
}

variant x;
x.t = INT;
x.i = 42;
displayGenericObject(x);
```

This isn't a very practical solution, but it works for trivial code that only needs a few types.

Comment: Could you please show an example of how you would call that struct to declare an item?

Comment: Aldo, there's vaarg to handle cases like this, but with it you need to somehow pass types on call (like `printf`). I bet you can get clever with macros here tho to make call fancy...

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it is not a good idea to write functions that take any argument. As noted in the comments, you lose on the compiler provided type-checking.

However, there are some cases where you might want to consider this using 'void *', which are (usually) considered acceptable are: (1) varargs functions and (2) callback. Important to emphasize that it is better to consider alternative implementation, if possible.

varargs functions are functions like 'printf', 'scanf', etc, where the function can accept variable number of arguments, potentially of different types, and will usually use clues (or convention) from the first arguments to properly decode the remaining arguments.

Callback are other example, where the code will sometimes have to specify a function that will be called on event. Many frameworks will require the callback to match a predefined "typedef", where the code will later cast the arguments into the actual type. For example, the 'qsort' prototype require a 'compar' function, which is generically defined to take 'void *', where the actual function will cast the parameters to the actual type.

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
                  int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

On historical note, the initial versions of "C" (sometimes call "K&R C") did allow functions to be defined without formal parameter list. Practical experience has proven this to be risky, non-productive. In those days, you could write function in header files like:

```
/* in file.h */
int foo() ;
/* in file.c */
int foo(a)
   int a ;
{
}
/* in prog.c */
{
    a(5,4,"x") ;
}
```